# How to know which website under an app service is consuming CPU

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure App Service Plan on the S3 tier which runs many websites. The service plan is spread across 3 instances. Occasionally I'm seeing periods of high CPU usage for the service plan coupled with general sluggish performance for all websites.

Is there a way (ideally through the portal) to see which website is consuming these resources without going into each of the individual sites? Similar to how a SQL Azure Elastic Pool shows which databases are consuming resources.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we could not find the web app CPU usage of each site in Azure App Service Plan. All apps related to a Azure App Service Plan share the same resource, it only gives Azure App Service plan CPU usage in Azure portal. At currently, I am afraid you need to go into each of the sites to find out which use the most.

Comment: @drew actually, it is possible to choose to show some other performance parameters - like Data in, Data out, Disk Queue Length, Http Queue Length - just have to choose "Edit" - and select those other parameters (but it seams, that 2 parameters can be selected at the same time)